# how to apply a css code for a specific screen size

Tags: theming

i am new in Drupal , in my case i have added a css code to implement it for just a specific width but in return i see it displayed for all screen size not the small or medium size it appears in all website's size, i wonder where is the problem here ? See the code below

libraries.yml

```
global-styling:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    js/popper.min.js: {}
    js/bootstrap.min.js: {}
    js/global.js: {}
  css:
    component:
      css/style.css: {}
      css/small.css: {breakpoint: small}
      css/medium.css: {breakpoint: medium}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal
```

breakpoints.yml

```
mymodule.small:
  label: small
  mediaQuery: 'all and (min-width: 740px) and (min-device-width: 740px)'
  weight: 0
  multipliers:
    - 1x
mymodule.medium:
  label: medium
  mediaQuery: 'all and (min-width: 1300px)'
  weight: 1
  multipliers:
    - 1x
```

css code :

```
body {
  background: red !important;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem here? The breakpoint option simply does not exist at all. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-theme#css-properties

Comment: The problem is that i want to apply 'background : red ' for just the specific width 'small and medium'

Comment: Then write a proper media query in your CSS file. It is the same mediaQuery syntax as used by responsive images / breakpoints.yml . See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Where did you come up with this syntax: `css/small.css: {breakpoint: small}`? If this is real, at a minimum you would need to use `breakpoint: mymodule.small`, but I've never heard of this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never herd of "breakpoints.yml" and don't think you can do what you want like that

so i think you just need to make normal media queries  in your css file "css/style.css" if you want you can break them out in to other files but
really there is no need.

Example:

```
// Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
@media (max-width: 575.98px) { ... }

// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767.98px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991.98px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199.98px) { ... }

// Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

Comment: E.g. responsive images module can use `MYTHEME.breakpoints.yml`